# Choosing a number at random.

Tags: probability

Assume $n$ people choose a number between $1$ and $k$ uniformly at random. What is the probability that any two of the $n$ people get the same number?
 I have found your answer to be

$P =   1   - \dfrac{    k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)....(k-n+3)(k-n+2)(k-n+1)}{k^n}$

$=      1   - \dfrac{ k!}{k^n(k-n)!}$

I would like some help in how to reduce the long equation to the short formula

Comment: Is n>k? If so, it's guaranteed, via the pigeonhole principle.  If not, then it may need other things to help it out. I'm guessing by uniformly at random, you mean independent of each other, if so there are n^k ways to choose the numbers.

Comment: doh $k^n$ yes I messed up before.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiply numerator and denominator by $(k-n)!$ and then simplify the numerator